# Returning results from VLOOKUP when the matches required are embedded within text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using VLOOKUP but the Lookup_Value I have is a number and the Table_Array I'm looking up has the number inside text; i.e. I'm looking for '200' but the search column is 'abc200a' or 'abcd200 Aa 10'.

How do I obtain a match despite the surrounding text, since trim functions only trim *n* characters left or right?

Thanks

Comment: `=VLOOKUP("*"&"200"&"*",...`

Comment: Thanks Scott! appreciate it